# Is there one to one correspondence between $C^k$ structure and $C^\infty$ structure on the topological manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

We know that given a topological manifold,which admit a $C^k$ structure can always makes into a $C^\infty$ structure on this manifold ,which is shown in Hirsch's differential topology book Theorem 2.10:

> (a) Let $1 \leqslant r<\infty .$ Every $C^{r}$ manifold is $C^{r}$ diffeomorphic to a $ C^{\infty}$ manifold.
>
> (b) Let $1 \leqslant r<s \leqslant \infty$. If two $C^{s}$ manifolds
> are $C^{r}$ diffeomorphic, they are $C^{s}$ diffeomorphic.

**The question is does the set of $C^k$ structure on $M$ one to one correspond to $C^\infty$ structure on $M$?(two structures are the same if there is a corresponding isomorphism between them)**

I think it's correct since:
Given any $C^\infty$ structure,when forget the other orders it gives one $C^k$ altalas,if we extend it to maximal altalas give one $C^k$ structure( which is $C^k$ diffeomorphic to original smooth structure)

it's injective since any $C^\infty $ equivalent structure is also $C^k$ equivalent.By the theroem (a) this map is surjective,hence upto isomorphic ,the $C_k$ structure are one to one correspond to $C^\infty$ structure is my idea correct?

Does this means these two categories which are category of smooth manifold and $C^k$ manifold are isomorphic ?

Comment: No, you're making a statement about isomorphism classes, which would at best yield an equivalence of categories. However (and more importantly), the morphisms in these two categories are completely different, there's tons of $C^k$ maps that are not $C^{\infty}$. The categorical state of affairs is that the forgetful functor $C^{\infty}-\mathbf{Man}\rightarrow C^k-\mathbf{Man}$ is faithful, essentially surjective and reflects isomorphisms, but not full.

Comment: Oh.. thank you,the theorem above (a) says that the forgetful functor is essentially surjective and theroem (b) says that it's reflects isomorphism correct?this is non trivial compared with $Top \to Set$ @Thorgott